# Datetime conversion - slow in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe which looks like this :

```
date,time,metric_x
2016-02-27,00:00:28.0000000,31
2016-02-27,00:01:19.0000000,40
2016-02-27,00:02:55.0000000,39
2016-02-27,00:03:51.0000000,48
2016-02-27,00:05:22.0000000,42
2016-02-27,00:05:59.0000000,35
```

I wish to generate a new column

```
df['time_slot'] = df.apply(lambda row: time_slot_convert(pd.to_datetime(row['time'])), axis =1)
```

Where,

```
def time_slot_convert(time):
    return time.hour + 1
```

This functions finds the hour for this record, plus 1.

This is extremely slow. I understand that the data is read as a string. is there a more efficient way that will speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster is remove `apply`:

```
df['time_slot'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour + 1

print (df)
         date              time  metric_x  time_slot
0  2016-02-27  00:00:28.0000000        31          1
1  2016-02-27  00:01:19.0000000        40          1
2  2016-02-27  00:02:55.0000000        39          1
3  2016-02-27  00:03:51.0000000        48          1
4  2016-02-27  00:05:22.0000000        42          1
5  2016-02-27  00:05:59.0000000        35          1
```